# Android TextToSpeech only working in Debug mode

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, text-to-speech

I have the following Kotlin code in a dialog where I want to use TextToSpeech.

```
                val tts = TextToSpeech(context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {status->
                if(status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    Timber.w("Text to speech issue. Status was ERROR.")
                }
            })

            tts.language = Locale.getDefault()

            val thread = Thread {
                tts.speak(getString(R.string.speed_voice_enabled), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null)
            }

            thread.start()

            val handler = Handler()

            handler.postDelayed( Runnable() {
                run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, 1500);  //1.5 seconds
```

If I set a breakpoint at the tts.speak line, then hit F9 to allow it to continue, the speech comes through loud and clear. If I remove that breakpoint, then nothing, no matter how long I set the delay for the dismissal of the dialog.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: do you wait until the TextToSpeech is intialized? For me it seems that doing a short break lets the initialization finish and therefor it works

Comment: I put in the delay above. I would think that would do it. Maybe not though.